# Selecting NumPy array range, including the last element

Tags: python, numpy

If I want to select all elements of a NumPy array, up to index N, I can write:

```
x = my_array[:N]
```

For example, if I want to select all elements, up to index 5, I can write:

```
N = 5
x = my_array[:N]
```

Or, if I want to select all elements, up to and including the penultimate element, I can write:

```
N = -1
x = my_array[:N]
```

But what if I want to select all elements up to and including the final element? How can I do this using the above notation?

I tried:

```
N = -0
x = my_array[:N]
```

But this returns a blank array.

p.s. Yes, I could just write out `x = my_array[:]`, but I need it to be in the format `my_array[:N]`, where `N` is defined dynamically.

Comment: Just leave out that value, i.e. `array[:]` is going to give all. Or do `array[:len(array)]`.

Comment: I need to have it in the format `my_array[:N]`, such that `N` can be dynamically defined

Comment: Then use `N = len(array)`. Actually you can use any `N >= len(array)` for that purpose. Also `N = None` will do.

Comment: `np.s_[::]` produces: `slice(None, None, None)`.

Comment: either `N == len(array)` or `N == None` should work, I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your method:

```
N = len(my_array)
x = my_array[:N]
```

You could then specify any arbitrary value of N if you only wish to slice up to that index. You could also specify the length of your array directly, if known.

To illustrate this...

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
N = len(my_array)
x = my_array[:N]
my_array == x
```

...returns True.